# Can't I multiply functions by members of the domain set?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Not sure if I worded that question correctly.

I just started learning linear algebra.  I'm using Sheldon Axler's 'Linear Algebra Done Right.'  The book is talking about scalar multiplication with function sets.  It says that $\lambda$ is a member of F (F and S are sets of either real or complex numbers, doesn't matter), and f is a member of the set of functions $F^s$.  Then it defines $(\lambda f)(x)=\lambda f(x)$, where x is a member of S.

It doesn't say whether or not $\lambda$ could also be a member of S.  So that's my question.  Could it be?

Comment: (If I understand your question) There is no need to define a type of multiplication between vectors (which are the functions here) when speaking of vector spaces.

Answer (score 0):

In general, with scalar multiplication, you have a vector space $V$ and a field $F$, and the scalar multiplication is a function:

$F \times V \to V$.

However, $V$ may be a set of functions:

$f: S \to F$.

Even if $S$ is just a "plain set" (with no operations defined on it) we can use the fact that $F$ (being a field) has a field addition to "add functions":

Given $f,g:S \to F$, we define $f+g$ "point-wise", by:

$(f+g)(s) = f(s) + g(s)$.

Note that the "summed functions" (on the left) represents the "vector addition" (our $V$ is the set of functions), and the sum on the right is addition in the field, $F$.

But a sum operation alone does not give us vector space structure-we also need a notion of scalar multiplication. So for a scalar $\lambda \in F$, we define the function $\lambda f : S \to F$ in a similar fashion:

$(\lambda f)(s) = \lambda \cdot f(s)$

Note that here, again, the product on the left is a scalar product:

$(\lambda,f) \mapsto \lambda f$ (scalar times vector = vector)

and the product on the right is the "ordinary" field multiplication of $F$.

Just to be clear: in this $\lambda \in F$ (it is a scalar), and $f \in V$ (it is a vector). The "image" of $f$ at $s$, $f(s)$ is also a scalar-don't confuse the image of a function with the function itself!

It does happen, however, that sometimes $S = F$. It is quite common to consider, for example, the vector space of functions $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$. But this does not HAVE to happen. The "algebraic structure" of our function space comes from the structure it's co-domain (target set) has, and $S$ (the domain) need not have any structure at all.

An simple example, to hopefully show you what I mean:

Let $S = \{a,b\}$, and let $F = \Bbb R$. Any function $f: \{a,b\} \to \Bbb R$ is just a(n ordered) pair of real numbers:

$x = f(a)$

$y = f(b)$.

We could represent this as $(x,y)_f$ with the understanding that $x$ is the image of $a$, and $y$ is the image of $b$.

Suppose $g(a) = x'$ and $g(b) = y'$. We compute the function $f+g$:

$(f+g)(a) = f(a) + g(a) = x + x'$

$(f+g)(b) = f(b) + g(b) = y + y'$

Written another way, we see $(x,y)_f + (x',y')_g = (x+x', y+y')_{f+g}$

Now the scalar multiplication: let $\lambda \in \Bbb R$. by our (point-wise) definition, we have:

$(\lambda f)(a) = \lambda\cdot f(a) = \lambda x$

$(\lambda f)(b) = \lambda \cdot f(b) = \lambda y$

In our "alternate notation" this says:

$\lambda (x,y)_f = (\lambda x,\lambda y)_{\lambda f}$

In this example $af$ "makes no sense", because we don't even know if $a$ is even a real number (it might stand for "building A", for example).

This example should seem "suspiciously similar" to the ordinary vector space $\Bbb R^2$ (except for the "tagging" of the pairs with their function names).